# Firebase Notification comes but it's not popping up on background state. Instead of it all works

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-notification

When I am sending a message from the Firebase console, In the foreground state it comes with a popup message. But the problem comes when the app is in a background state. The message comes in the status bar but **not popUp** on the screen.

Here is my notification service code.

```
Future<void> initLocalNotification(
      BuildContext context, RemoteMessage message) async {
    var androidInitialaztionSetting = new AndroidInitializationSettings(
      '@mipmap/ic_launcher',
    );

    var iosInitialaztionSetting = new DarwinInitializationSettings();

    var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
      android: androidInitialaztionSetting,
      iOS: iosInitialaztionSetting,
    );

    await FirebaseMessaging.instance
        .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true, // Required to display a heads up notification
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );

    await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings,
      onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (payload) {
        handleMessage(context, message);
      },
    );

    showNotification(message);
  }
```

Here is another

```
void showNotification(RemoteMessage message) async {
    // AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
    //     Random.secure().nextInt(100000).toString(), 'No name',
    //     importance: Importance.max);

    const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
      'high_importance_channel', // id
      'High Importance Notifications', // title
      description:
          'This channel is used for important notifications.', // description
      playSound: true,
      showBadge: true,
      enableLights: true,
      enableVibration: true,
      importance: Importance.max,
    );

    AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
      channel.id,
      channel.name,
      playSound: true,
      enableLights: true,
      enableVibration: true,
      channelDescription: 'your channel description',
      importance: Importance.high,
      priority: Priority.high,
      ticker: 'ticker',
      largeIcon: const DrawableResourceAndroidBitmap("ic_launcher"),
      styleInformation: const MediaStyleInformation(
        htmlFormatContent: true,
        htmlFormatTitle: true,
      ),
    );

    DarwinNotificationDetails darwinNotificationDetails =
        const DarwinNotificationDetails(
            presentAlert: true, presentBadge: true, presentSound: true);

    NotificationDetails notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(
      android: androidNotificationDetails,
      iOS: darwinNotificationDetails,
    );

    await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
      _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        1, // id
        message.notification!.title, // title
        message.notification!.body, // body
        notificationDetails,
      );
    });
  }
```

handling the background message from top-level function.

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);

  // for handling background messages
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseBackgroundHandler);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    debugPrint(message.notification!.title);
  }
```

Comment: In your testing phone, go to settings and make sure badges are enabled for the channel you are sending notifications to.

Comment: all notification permission allowed there.